# Declaring functions using a require statement inside a Node.js class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, require, es6-module-loader

I am willing to define class methods by using `require` statements. As follows:

```js
class A {

  constructor () {}

  static functionA = require('./someFileA');
  static functionB = require('./someFileB');

  functionC = require('./someFileC');

}
```

Will there be any possible performance/memory leaks issues on doing this instead of doing all the requires at the beginning of the file (prior the Class definition) and then using them to define the methods?

*(I'm using Node 12)*

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Doing it for static methods might be fine (although personally I find it absolutely ugly). Doing it for instance methods, by abusing class fields, is absolutely not - it's both a performance and a correctness issue, very similar to [that of arrow functions](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!! Sorry to ask, but could you explain just a little bit more why it should be considered a correctness and performance issue when doing it for instance methods?

Comment: Did you read the linked article about putting functions in class fields?